# Wants to find exact location of a object inside a boundary

Tags: tcl

I am a SoC design engineer.

My situation is this: there's a square/rectangular chip/die (coordinates of that are fixed), for now suppose "X is 1000 micron and Y is also 1000 micron". Need to place some square/rectangular objects inside this 1000 by 1000 boundary and these objects/cells have some coverage/range lets say each cell can cover 100 micron in each direction (i.e. 100 micron in north,south,east and west), which means next object/cell in each direction to be placed at 200 micron from centre of the first one.

My objective is to calculate the number and co-ordinates (exact position) of those objects so that these objects can cover the entire 1000 by 1000 area.

I am not that good at coding, just looking for a direction to proceed. Any help appreciated!

Comment: `(width * height) / ((coverage * 2) ^ 2)` => 1000 * 1000 / (100 * 2)^2 = 25. Or `(width / (coverage * 2)) * (height / (coverage * 2))`, optionally rounding after each sub division.

Comment: Tcl uses `**` to mean exponentiation instead of `^` (which means XOR, a legacy of C).

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 , I appreciate your taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key points (made by @luk2302 in the comments on your question) is that you need to allocate a whole number of units along each dimension. This makes the calculation not just a matter of dividing the area of the whole by the area of each unit. With calculations like this, it's easiest to break them into several pieces.

```
# Input data; could use fractional numbers here too if that works better
set width 1000
set height 1000
# I'm not assuming square subunits
set coverage_x 100
set coverage_y 100

# Calculate number in X direction
set x_count [expr { int($width / ($coverage_x * 2.0)) }]

# Calculate number in Y direction
set y_count [expr { int($height / ($coverage_y * 2.0)) }]

# Get the number actually possible
set total_count [expr { $x_count * $y_count }]
puts "Predicted total count is $total_count"
```

Now, to get the coordinates we need to use a nested pair of loops, which need to start at one coverage unit in from the edge (since we're after the center point) and proceed until the far edge goes off the overall die:

```
for {set y $coverage_y} {$y + $coverage_y > $height} {set y [expr {$y + $coverage_y * 2}]} {
    for {set x $coverage_x} {$y + $coverage_x > $width} {set y [expr {$y + $coverage_x * 2}]} {
        puts "place at ($x,$y)"
    }
}
```

I've just printed the results. *Many* other options are possible.

---

## Guide to reading

The Tcl commands I've used are:

- `set` — writes a value to a variable
- `expr` — evaluates an expression
- `for` — does a loop (with setup, test, step, and body clauses)
- `puts` — prints a string so you can read it

Remember with Tcl, `$x` means “read variable `x`”, `[blah]` means evaluate `blah` and use its result here, and `{flerg}` and `"some thing"` are types of quoting.

Comment: Thanks @Donal for your effort and taking the time, this is something puts me on right path. I will surely get back to you guys once I am done with it.